# CSS Grid Layout on WordPress Category Page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, css-grid

I have created a grid to display posts on a WordPress site.  The grid works great and scales to different devices using minmax and auto-fit, but the problem I'm having is that the last 2 spots in the grid on each page are always empty even if I have more posts that can fill the space.  For example, on this category page: https://2ndactcostumes.com/category/fans-collars-belts/
I have two pages of posts, but space is being wasted at the bottom of the first page.  Any ideas on how to remedy this?  Thank you!!
(edited)
Category.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div class="page-wrapper">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

      <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <h1><?php the_archive_title( '' ); ?></h1>


        <hr />
        <div class="article-container">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

          <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-posts-costume' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
          <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>

        </main>
      

    </div>

  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Template-parts code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"  <?php post_class(); ?>>

  <header class="entry-header">

    <?php the_title( '<h2><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>

  </header>

  <div class="entry-content">

    <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size = 'thumbnail' ); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

  </div>



</article>
```

CSS for the grid:

```
.category main .article-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(275px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: See:  [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: When I click the link you provided, I see that most of the grids have equally distributed items.  I'm betting you had the default 10 items that WordPress returns and that you specified you wanted 12 instead.  This works better in a grid.  Thanks for updating us so we know how it worked out!